# JOIN Across 3 tables

Tags: sql, select, join

I am trying to join together 3 tables and potentially retrieve data from any of the columns.

I have a product and a lifestyle and a 'mapping table' that essentially contains references between the 2.

I want to do it properly using joins - but it is proving troublesome. If i use 'WHEREs' it works.

Here it is

This returns more results than I expect - it is probably doing the right thing, just not what I want!

```
SELECT DISTINCT PROFDESC.* 
FROM PROFDESC 
INNER JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODFUND.PRODCD = PRODUCT.PRODCD 
INNER JOIN PRODFUND ON PRODFUND.PDFDCODE = PROFDESC.PROFREF 
WHERE PRODFUND.PDFDTYPE = 2
```

This works fine but doesn't 'join' the tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PROFDESC.* 
FROM PROFDESC, Product, Prodfund 
WHERE 
PRODFUND.PRODCD = PRODUCT.PRODCD and  
PRODFUND.PDFDCODE = PROFDESC.PROFREF 
AND PRODFUND.PDFDTYPE = 2;
```

I believe my first one is literally joining A to B and B to C where as I want the connection to include A to C

any suggestions?

Comment: can you provide table definations and expected result with some dummy data?

Comment: can you give us the structure of the tables? I think both querys are wrong. In the first one you're joinining, in the first join, by using the table on the third join

Comment: Read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: What RDBMS is this? Using `DISTINCT PROFDESC.* ` to eliminate duplicates brought in by the joins is a code smell and should probably be replaced by `EXISTS` anyway assuming you are using a RDBMS that optimises this OK.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to have the tables in the query previously defined. This should work fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PROFDESC.* 
FROM PROFDESC 
INNER JOIN PRODFUND ON PRODFUND.PDFDCODE = PROFDESC.PROFREF     
INNER JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODFUND.PRODCD = PRODUCT.PRODCD 
WHERE PRODFUND.PDFDTYPE = 2
```

Comment: A chiastic relationship according to Itzik Ben Gan. Still doesn't explain why they say they are getting more rows than they expect rather than a parser error.

Comment: Yes, I would be good to know the relationship between the tables. Which tables are on the one side, which on the n side?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the correct order when joining

```
SELECT DISTINCT PROFDESC.*
FROM
    PROFDESC
    INNER JOIN PRODFUND
        ON PROFDESC.PROFREF = PRODFUND.PDFDCODE
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT
        ON PRODFUND.PRODCD = PRODUCT.PRODCD  
WHERE
    PRODFUND.PDFDTYPE = 2
```

But why are you joining to PRODUCT? You are not referring to any columns of it. Does the join somehow narrow the result? If not, drop it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PROFDESC.*
FROM
    PROFDESC
    INNER JOIN PRODFUND
        ON PROFDESC.PROFREF = PRODFUND.PDFDCODE
WHERE
    PRODFUND.PDFDTYPE = 2
```

Maybe the DISTINCT can be dropped then (depending on the cardinality of the join).